# Change ID of returned array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following method:

```
$results = array_filter($arr['people'], function($people) use ($searchId) {
    return in_array($searchId, $people['member']);
});

echo json_encode($results);
```

This returnes an array like this:

```
[{"id":"8080","content":"foo","member":[123,456],"interval":7}]
```

But if there more than one result it will return this:

```
["0": {"id":"8080","content":"foo","member":[123,456],"interval":7}]
["5": {"id":"8082","content":"bar","member":[1234,3456],"interval":5}]
```

I want to replace the "automatically" given ID with the ID which is in the Array - like this:

```
["8080": {"id":"8080","content":"foo","member":[123,456],"interval":7}]
["8082": {"id":"8082","content":"bar","member":[1234,3456],"interval":5}]
```

Have somebody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,

```
$arr = [
    0 => [
        "id"       => 8082,
        "content"  => "test",
        "interval" => "7",
    ],
    5 => [
        "id"       => 8086,
        "content"  => "test",
        "interval" => "7",
    ],
];

$ids    = array_column($arr, "id");
$result = array_combine($ids, $arr);
print_r($result);
echo json_encode($result);
```

[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which states Return the values from a single column in the input array.
[array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) which states Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way :

```
$arr[$newkey] = $arr[$oldkey];
unset($arr[$oldkey]);
```

Comment: This is clearly a bad solution. You might unset ID's you don't want to unset.